# Unusual behavior for the same swing code in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have two almost similar code.

**Code I**

```
   JFrame pFrame=new NetBeansFrame();
   JPanel myPanel=new myPanel();
   pFrame.add(myPanel);
   Dimension windowDim=myPanel.getSize();

   pFrame.pack();
   pFrame.getContentPane().setSize(windowDim.width-100,windowDim.height-50);
   pFrame.setVisible(true);
```

**Code II**

```
   JFrame pFrame=new JFrame();
   JPanel myPanel=new myPanel();
   pFrame.add(myPanel);
   Dimension windowDim=myPanel.getSize();

   pFrame.pack();
   pFrame.getContentPane().setSize(windowDim.width-100,windowDim.height-50);
   pFrame.setVisible(true);
```

In Code I,NetBeansFrame is a frame that I created using netbeans->Jframe and named it NetBeansFrame.It contains nothing.I added the panel into it using codeI.

**NetBeansFrame.java**

```
public class NetBeansFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public NetBeansFrame() {
    initComponents();

}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 407, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 429, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetBeansFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetBeansFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetBeansFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetBeansFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new NetBeansFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
```

}

In Code II,I am creating a frame from JFrame.Logically both the codes are equivalent.

*But on executing Code I,the panel does not appear in netbeansFrame while for Code II the panel appears.*

So,I want to know that what may be the cause for this unusual behavior for almost same code.

Comment: This is very hard to troubleshoot without the source for NetBeansFrame.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson:thnx for suggesting SSCCE link.. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. `Dimension windowDim=myPanel.getSize();` returned only `Dimension[0, 0]`, becasue returned `Dimension` from

   - already visible container (in your case with components `JPanel`)
   - after called `pack();`
2. then `pFrame.getContentPane().setSize(windowDim.width-100,windowDim.height-50);` returned `Dimension[-100, -50]`
3. you can

   - if `JPanel` is empty then returns its `PreferredSize`
   - if `JPanel` is not empty, then its `JComponents` returns `PreferredSize` you can to try that with to remove/disable code line `pFrame.getContentPane().setSize(windowDim.width-100,windowDim.height-50);`

Comment: Now my code is
    `JFrame pFrame=new NetBeansFrame();
       JPanel myPanel=new myPanel();
       pFrame.add(myPanel);
       
        
        pFrame.pack();
        
        pFrame.setVisible(true);`


even though it does not come.

Comment: @Abhinav: Try adding component or two to `myPanel`. For better readability, edit your question to include new code.